# window.onmousemove and document.onmousemove doesn't capture iframe events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used a script where I am trying to capture the mouse move events but it is working on whole page except the IFrame.

Earlier my code had window.onmousemove used. Later I tried with document.onmousemove as well, but it didn't work.

```
    function CheckActivity() {
               document.onload = resetTimer;
               document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
               document.onmousedown = resetTimer;
               document.onclick = resetTimer;
               document.onscroll = resetTimer;
               document.onkeypress = resetTimer;

            function resetTimer() {
                localStorage.setItem("activityDate", new Date());
            }
      }
```

How can I capture the events over an IFrame?